# SQLServer - MERGE with condition is slow, even an "always false" condition

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, merge

I want to execute the MERGE statement conditionally, so it won't try to match the entire target-table.
My original statement was kinda like this:

```
MERGE [target_table] USING [table_source]
ON (([target_table].[ID] = [table_source].[ID]) AND (condition))
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
SET [table_source].[_strField1] = [table_source].[_strField2];
```

Note: assume '_strField' to be typed as nvarchar(4000), and 'condition' to be something like [target_table].[_strField8] = 'sometext'.

But then I've encountered the following warning in the [documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) that dictates `"...Do not attempt to improve query performance by filtering out rows in the target table in the ON clause"`.

So my original query was altered to the following one

```
MERGE [target_table] USING [table_source]
ON (([target_table].[ID] = [table_source].[ID]))
WHEN MATCHED AND (condition) 
THEN UPDATE
SET [table_source].[_strField] = [table_source].[_strField];
```

The problem is, that the query now takes a lot more time. Even changing the condition to be "always false", such as **1 = 2** doesn't help at all. On the other hand, setting different fields, such as

```
SET [table_source].[_intField] = [table_source].[_intField];
```

or any other types other than two nvarchar(4000)s causes the statement to be executed much faster.

To conclude, the things I don't understand are:

- If the data-setting of nvarchar(4000) is the longer process, why setting the condition to be "1 = 2" doesn't speed up the execution time?
- If the "row-matching" is the longer process, why setting INT fields does speed up the execution time?

Comment: Please post some (actual) execution plans as .sqlplan. They allow us to see exactly what is going wrong. And yes, I think your results are curious and should be investigated.

Answer (score 0):

According to sql server documentation:

"...Do not attempt to improve query performance by filtering out rows in the target table in the ON clause, such as by specifying AND NOT target_table.column_x = value. **Doing so may return unexpected and incorrect results**..*

your first query is invalid. You should not take time results into consideration.

If you update column with fixed lenght (int,date) there will be no "Row-Overflow Data Exceeding 8 KB" situation. This situation can occurs when you use nvarchar(4000) and give poor query performance.

We do not now how the merge function works inside and how it process data. So propably only developers of this function can give You answers to your question.

I hope that I have help you with varchar(4000) performance issue.

Marcin Pazgier

Comment: We actually *can* peek inside using the execution plan.